# Radiogroup and radiobuttin design in the table row dynamically

Tags: android, radio-button, radio-group

```
how to align this

private TableRow nappyRow(int id) {
    System.out.println("***nappies_list **get id*****"+id);     
    TableRow.LayoutParams rowParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
            TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0, 1f);

    TableRow.LayoutParams itemParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
            TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1);

    TableRow.LayoutParams rg_params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 2f);

    TableRow table_row = new TableRow(this);
    table_row.setLayoutParams(rowParams);

    final TextView when = new TextView(this);
    RadioGroup radio_group=new RadioGroup(this);
    radio_group.setOrientation(RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL);
    radio_group.setLayoutParams(rg_params);
    radio_group.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);



    RadioButton dry=new RadioButton(this);
    RadioButton wet=new RadioButton(this);
    RadioButton soiled=new RadioButton(this);   

    RadioGroup.LayoutParams button_params = new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,0.4f);

    //button_params.setMargins(40, 0, 0, 0);                
    dry.setLayoutParams(button_params);
    wet.setLayoutParams(button_params);
    soiled.setLayoutParams(button_params);      

    dry.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.custom_radio_button);
    wet.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.custom_radio_button);
    soiled.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.custom_radio_button);

    radio_group.addView(dry);
    radio_group.addView(wet);
    radio_group.addView(soiled);

    // creating the add icon
    ImageView img_nappy = new ImageView(this);
    img_nappy.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_tick2);

    ImageView img_cream = new ImageView(this);
    img_cream.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_tick2_disabled);

    // creating the add icon
    ImageView icon = new ImageView(this);
    icon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_add);

    // setting the layout parames
    when.setLayoutParams(itemParams);


    // Setting alignment
    when.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);


    // setting text
    when.setText("00:00");


    LinearLayout icon_layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.5f);
    params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
    icon_layout.setLayoutParams(params);
    icon_layout.addView(icon);

    Integer max_list = Collections.max(nappies_list);

    if (id == max_list) {
        System.out.println("add::" + id);
        icon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_add);
    } else {
        System.out.println("delete::" + id);
        icon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_delete);
    }

    // adding the widget into table row
    table_row.addView(when);
    table_row.addView(radio_group);

    table_row.addView(icon_layout);
    table_row.addView(img_nappy);
    table_row.addView(img_cream);

    icon.setId(id);
    icon_layout.setId(id);


    //click on the plus button
    icon_layout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {          
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Integer max_list = Collections.max(nappies_list);

            if(v.getId() < max_list){
                Logger.e("**********", "remove");
                nappies_list.remove(v.getId());                 
                nappies();
                System.out.println("nappies_list::::::::::::" + nappies_list);
            }else{
                Logger.e("**********", "add");
                nappies_list.add(bottle_list.size() + 1);
                nappies();
                System.out.println("nappies_list::::::::::::" + nappies_list);
            }

            System.out.println("click id::::::::::::" + v.getId());
            System.out.println("size nappies_list::::::::::::"
                    + nappies_list.size());
            System.out.println("max_list::::::::::::" + max_list);
            System.out.println("nappies_list::::::::::::" + nappies_list);  

        }
    });     

    table_row.setPadding(0, 12, 0, 12);
    return table_row;
}
```

Comment: Try to add the image again or just add the link directly if you can't.